# Can Spinnaker be integrated with a Jenkins instance using non-basic authentication?

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

According to the Spinnaker docs, Jenkins must be deployed with basic auth to allow integration. My Jenkins server uses Github authentication - does this mean I cannot integrate the two?

I have tried and there is a connection error when retrieving jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor (the service that connects Spinnaker to Jenkins) [only supports basic auth](https://github.com/spinnaker/igor/blob/release-1.3.x/igor-web/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/igor/config/JenkinsConfig.groovy#L72) at the moment.

However, it looks like you can use a github token alongside jenkins http basic auth to [get around this problem](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+OAuth+Plugin#GitHubOAuthPlugin-CallingJenkinsAPIusingGitHubPersonalAccessTokens):

```
jenkins:
  username: <github_user>
  password: <github_oauth_token>
```